# Find the IDs and names of the employees whose salaries are at least 10% higher than the average salary of all employees

Tags: mariadb

I need to find the IDs and names of the employees whose salaries are at least 10% higher than the average salary of all employees. I can't get the code to work with the 10% higher than the average. I know how to get the average, but when I run my particular code, I get all names and know that it's not running correctly.

Here is my query:

```
Select employees.eid, 
       CONCAT(efirstName, 
       ' ', eLastName) AS Name 
from employees 
GROUP BY employees.salary 
HAVING employees.salary > avg(salary * .10);
```

I have also tried:

```
Select employees.eid, 
       CONCAT(eFirstName, 
       ' ', 
       eLastName AS Name 
FROM employees 
GROUP by eLastName 
HAVING avg(salary) > avg(salary * .10);
```

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Select employees.eid, CONCAT(efirstName, ' ', eLastName) AS Name from employees GROUP BY employees.salary HAVING employees.salary > avg(salary * .10);                                                                                                                                            I have also tried:         Select employees.eid, CONCAT(eFirstName, ' ', eLastName AS Name FROM employees GROUP by eLastName HAVING avg(salary) > avg(salary * .10);

Comment: @Marco See above comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a simple subquery should help with this:

```
SELECT e.eid, CONCAT(efirstname, ' ', e.elastname) name
FROM employees e
WHERE e.salary > (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM employees) * 1.10
```

Comment: @Ashley Then give it the check mark

Answer (score -2):

Can u try this:

```
    SELECT e.eid, concat(e.eFirstName, ' ', e.LastName) as name
    FROM employees e
    WHERE e.salary > AVG(e.salary) * 0.1;
```

Comment: I get invalid use of group function